# Can you check if $(this).addClass('selected') has already been added in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
    $("#UpdateTable tr").click(function ()
{
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

It highlights a row in a table when that row is selected. Is there a way to check to see if the row is already selected or is the currently selected row?

I am trying to be able to select a row and have it be highlighted, then select that same row again and have the highlighting go away. But I'm new to jquery and don't know how to do the check.

Comment: .hasClass can be used if the row is already selected

Comment: @Deep That worked perfectly Thanks!

Comment: The answer for this question is alredy on Google Search! Please searching before ask

Comment: You may also wish to look into toggle (http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: @HappyCoding –If so, do flag the question instead of making illogical comments...

Comment: look into `toggleClass()`

Comment: @dandavis – `toggleClass()` seems to be best possible solution...

Comment: @Rayon What's happen if I try to doing that? Block my account? Couldn't I tell OP that he can find the asnwer faster?

Comment: @HappyCoding – Google Search is probably not most appropriate source to suggest someone.. I am quiet sure that there are many duplicate/related posts like this and you are free to flag so... _Google_ will probably return `n^n` answers to all the questions and neither of them may not answer the question...

Comment: @Rayon How do you use Google Search for this case? Keywords `jquery class already` are enough

Comment: @HappyCoding – Both `Google` and `SO` are totally different platforms... Suggesting any over other is not the purpose of `SO`..

Comment: @Rayon ya. so many questions, so many answers, so many documents. and you don't have time to read 3 - 5 of top result to select one. Bad english? Poor experience? Or...?

Comment: @HappyCoding – Almost all the questions asked over _SO_ have answers or related content over _Google_, Do you expect everyone to stop using `SO` and search over `Google` instead ?

Comment: @Rayon I don't prevent any action. If I have the moderator power, I will flag this question is duplicate. Someone couldn't know how to post a good question, but they can know: `Has SO an answer for the question?` Right?

Comment: @HappyCoding – There is no need to have moderator privilege to fal a question.. Even you do not know many things over `SO`, How can you expect this from a person who has just joined the community ?

Comment: @Rayon **just joined**? ok. If you say that, I will say no more. I've given my suggestion: Google Search the keywords **jquery class already**. Of course, it's only my private idea.

Comment: @Rayon ya. I forget one thing. SO has soooooooooooo many persons who **just joined**. That's all

Comment: _"private idea"_ ? Do you mean _"Individual Opinion"_ ? Was someone talking about _"Bad English"_ ? Aah.. _My bad...._

Comment: @Rayon That means: Every beginner should start with Google Search instead of SO! SO is optional

Comment: @HappyCoding – Not really! Google may not answer all the question but SO mostly will... But question show express some sort of efforts....

Comment: @Rayon So, you should take a tour `How to use Google Search`. If you don't? No problem, post your question to SO and it would be flagged duplicate.

Comment: @HappyCoding – I have been around here since couple of years and have asked [__few questions__](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1746830/rayon?tab=questions) and neither of them is ever flagged or downvoted(One of them has got __9k__ views).. So kindly do not suggest me what to do and what not to do...

Comment: @Rayon haha. Don't angry with me. We're talking about this quetion, about beginners, about the fastest way to find the answer for some questions. Yes, I'm new. But that's everything I know when getting very downvoting. Reputation may say nothing :)

Comment: @HappyCoding – I do not see any downvote on this question either... Probably you are the only one who thinks otherwise.. OP has shown his efforts as well as provided context and the code....

Comment: @Rayon And... how about my suggestion? **jquery already class** on Google and read 3 - 5 of top results to select one?

Comment: Just so that you do know. I did do a search in Google first. I didn't know what key words to use, but they were similar to what is suggested here. However since I've only been using jquery since this morning Google had nothing to go on for preferences and I didn't find the correct answer. Now that I've asked this question using the same key words I now get my question at the top along with a couple of others that are similar, though not quite the same. Also, as a side note, I'm not new to SO I've been here for a number of years now.

Comment: @HappyCoding – [__How do I ask a good question?__](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) never mentioned anything about `Google` or any `Search-Engine` hence I find your comment _illogical..._

Comment: @Mike So, that's the reason you should take the tour I said. My keywords which I provide, it contains the information enough (and more) for your question. I **DO NOT** say: You don't post your question here, you don't have a power here... bla bla.... It's just a tip to use for future. Ok?

Comment: @Rayon That's only the reason for **Be using SO instead of Google Search**. Even if you see my keywords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#UpdateTable tr").click(function ()
{
    if($(this).hasClass('selected'))
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    else
        $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Do you not need to use `{}` in the `if`?

Comment: @Mike only if there are more than one sentence in that `if` :)

Comment: If you have single line of code following the "if" then you do not have to use the {}. But if you have a block of code then you must place it inside the {}

Comment: @nicael That makes sense.

Comment: How about `$("#UpdateTable tr").click(function ()
{
    $(this).toggleClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});` ?

Comment: @Rayon After seeing the comments about `toggleClass` above I did switch to that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).hasClass('selected')
```

[Read more on `hasClass()` here](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/).